# Variable value based on current month

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

what I am looking to do is declare and set variables and goal values for the entire year month by month and then just like the ‘Current GP’ select  I want the query to display the goal based on current month. I believe that it is possible.

```
 DECLARE @Today DATETIME = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
 DECLARE @StartOfCurrentMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Today), 0)
 DECLARE @EndOfCurrentMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(S, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Today)+1,0))
 DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(MM,0,@StartOfCurrentMonth)
 DECLARE @End DATETIME = @Today
 DECLARE @JAN dec
 DECLARE @FEB dec
 DECLARE @MAR dec
 DECLARE @APR dec
 DECLARE @MAY dec
 DECLARE @JUN dec
 DECLARE @JUL dec
 DECLARE @AUG dec
 DECLARE @SEP dec
 DECLARE @OCT dec
 DECLARE @NOV dec
 DECLARE @DEC dec


 SET @JAN = 100000.50
 SET @FEB = 100000.51
 SET @MAR = 100000.52
 SET @APR = 100000.53 
 SET @MAY = 100000.54
 SET @JUN = 100000.55 
 SET @JUL = 100000.56 
 SET @AUG = 100000.57
 SET @SEP = 100000.58
 SET @OCT = 100000.59
 SET @NOV = 100000.60
 SET @DEC = 100000.61  

 SELECT SUM(OINV.GrosProfit) AS 'Current GP', @MAY as 'Goal GP' 
 from OINV 
 where OINV.DocDate between @Start and @end
```

The above code is the extent of my abilities

Comment: You don't declare `@` variables in MySQL. Are you actually using SQL-Server?

Comment: Put the goals in a temporary table, then you can select the row based on the current month.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I am using SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cte (Create Table Month and Goal) and join with New table

```
 DECLARE @Today DATETIME = CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
 DECLARE @StartOfCurrentMonth DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@Today), 0)
 DECLARE @Start DATETIME = DATEADD(MM,0,@StartOfCurrentMonth)
 DECLARE @End DATETIME = @Today

 ;with _Lst as (
         select 1 MonthCode,100000.50 as GoalGP  union
         select 2 MonthCode,100000.51 as GoalGP  union
         select 3 MonthCode,100000.52 as GoalGP  union
         select 4 MonthCode,100000.53 as GoalGP  union
         select 5 MonthCode,100000.54 as GoalGP  union
         select 6 MonthCode,100000.55 as GoalGP   union
         select 7 MonthCode,100000.56 as GoalGP    union
         select 8 MonthCode,100000.57 as GoalGP    union
         select 9 MonthCode,100000.58 as GoalGP    union
         select 10 MonthCode,100000.59 as GoalGP    union
         select 10 MonthCode,100000.59 as GoalGP    union
         select 11 MonthCode,100000.60 as GoalGP    union
         select 12 MonthCode,100000.61 as GoalGP     
   )

   
 SELECT SUM(OINV.GrosProfit) AS 'Current GP',max( a.GoalGP) as 'Goal GP' from OINV 
 inner join (select * from _Lst  )a on  DATEPART(month, OINV.DocDate)=a.MonthCode
 where OINV.DocDate between @Start and @end
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/fj34Lya3)